# How to get a proper elastic collision in a rigid body simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to make a rigid body based Newton's cradle in Blender 2.80. At the moment my setup looks like this:
[image]

The constraints are hinges, rotated so the balls can only move left to right. After some experiments I used the Sphere shape for the collision, mesh or convex hull don't give any kind of elastic collision. I tried several values for friction or bounciness, but none give the proper motion I expect. I also experimented with collision margins, to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I put the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hZfnHJozy5W2Y6ANxwkBtBi-kArs3Npc) on google drive if someone wants to look at what I'm doing wrong.
I tried looking for a tutorial on youtube, but none of the ones I saw used rigid body, I only found this [final animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZw1yw_rjDM) of what I would like to achieve, which does use it, so it should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of my example still need to be fine-tuned.

[image: example]

[image]

#### General Rigid Body Tips

- Use the simplified rigid body shapes (where possible) and to [stabilize the simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137836/30849), amplify the scene's scale. (Don't use objects smaller than 1 Blender Unit.)
- Adjust the solver iterations. Too few iterations will result imperfect motions, to many will destabilize the simulation because floating point imprecisions will add up. (See [this last paragraph](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133611/30849).)

#### For Newton's Cradle

1. For the spheres you have correctly set the shape to *Sphere*. Increase the **Bounciness** to a high value ~ 1 and decrease the Friction to a low value ~0.
2. Add a small gap between the spheres!
3. To reduce extra velocity, enable **Split Impulse** in the Rigid Body World settings and use a Translation Damping value > 0 in the Rigid Bodies' Dynamics Settings.

[image: settings]

The stability of the simulation seems to be a delicate interaction of Rigid Body World **Iterations** and **Samples** and the **gap between the spheres**.

Comment: Awesome, that really helped. One thing you didn't mention that also improved the simulation was the fact you used longer pendulums, so there's also that.

Comment: You're right. I added a small paragraph with two other answers linked, which may be helpful. In future, feel free to edit the answer yourself and extend it with useful tips.